# Unable to run shell script inside Jenkins pipeline

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm able to run the following shell script but couldn't run from Jenkins pipeline code.

**Try 1.**

```
node('buildnode') {

def value = "Myvalue"

def key = "Mykey"

sh '''

DATA=$(printf "%-50s \"$key\"" "$value")

echo "$DATA"

'''

}
```

**output:**

```
++ printf '%-50s ' ''
+ DATA='
```

**Try 2:**

Tried with sh " " "

```
DATA=$(printf "%-50s \"$key\"" "$value")

echo "$DATA"

" " "
```

**output:** :

> illegal string body character after dollar sign;
>      solution: either escape a literal dollar sign `"\$5"` or bracket the value expression `"${5}"`

Can someone help me?

Comment: Try escaping the dollar sign for `DATA` (i.e., `echo "\$DATA"`).

Comment: tried but no use. out put - ++ printf '%-50s ' ''
+ DATA='                                                   '
+ echo '

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work.

```
node('buildnode') {
    def value = "Myvalue" 
    def key = "Mykey"

    sh """
    DATA=\$(printf "%-50s \"${key}\" \"${value}\"")
    echo "\$DATA"
    """
}
```

You also need to escape $ when calling new subshell under `""" """`

```
DATA=$(printf "%-50s \"${key}\" \"${value}\"")
```

Comment: Thanks. It actually worked. How Can I get double quotes for "value". I have tried-  DATA=\$(printf "%-50s \"${key}\" "\"${value}\""") but no luck.