# Jenkins pipeline shared library failed to retrieve pod IP

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, jq, kubectl, jenkins-groovy

I have created a Jenkins pipeline shared library to retrieve a pod IP connecting to a kubernetes cluster which fails throwing an error below. Any pointers for fixing this would be great:

JSL:

```
docker.withRegistry('https://' + dockerRegistry, dockerCredentialsId) {
    docker.image(kubectlImage).inside("""--entrypoint=''"""){
      sh """
      #!/bin/sh
      set +x
      kubectl get pods -n ${namespace}  -o json > $WORKSPACE/pods.json
      podIP=$(jq -r '.items[] | select(.metadata.generateName | test(\"${appName}\")).status.podIP' $WORKSPACE/pods.json}
      echo "Pod IP:$podIP"
      """
    }
  }
```

Error during the pipeline execution -

```
70: illegal string body character after dollar sign;
16:18:23     solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 70, column 14.
16:18:23           podIP=$(jq -r '.items[] | select(.metadata.generateName | test(\"${appName}\")).status.podIP' $WORKSPACE/pods.json)
16:18:23                  ^
16:18:23  
16:18:23  1 error
16:18:23  
16:18:23    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
16:18:23    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:150)
16:18:23    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:120)
16:18:23    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:132)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to run shell script inside Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50350713/unable-to-run-shell-script-inside-jenkins-pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

The `"""` syntax is for multiline-interpolated Groovy strings. This is not what you want in either of the usage above. We can use a single line literal string `'` and a multiline literal string instead:

```
docker.withRegistry('https://' + dockerRegistry, dockerCredentialsId) {
  docker.image(kubectlImage).inside('--entrypoint=""'){
    sh '''
    #!/bin/sh
    set +x
    kubectl get pods -n ${namespace}  -o json > $WORKSPACE/pods.json
    podIP=$(jq -r ".items[] | select(.metadata.generateName | test($appName)).status.podIP" $WORKSPACE/pods.json}
    echo "Pod IP:$podIP"
    '''
  }
}
```

Since `WORKSPACE` is a pipeline environment variable exported to the shell interpreter, it is fine as is. If you had used the interpolated syntax, it would need to have been accessed in the `env` object i.e. `env.WORKSPACE`.

The definition for `appName` is not shown in the question, so if that does not resolve as expected, then the question will need to be updated accordingly.